# Continuous random variable made of two classical variables

Tags: probability

Let $Z$ be the random variable defined as
$$
Z=Y+XY
$$
where $X$ follows a uniform law between $[-1,1]$ and $Y$ is a gaussian with parameter $(m,\sigma)$. I'm asked to find a set $D_{\alpha} \in \mathbb{R}^2$ such that th repartition function of $Z$ is
$$
F_{Z}\left(\alpha\right)=\iint_{D_{\alpha}}f\left(x,y\right)\text{d}x\text{d}y
$$
with $f$ the density of the join law $\left(X,Y\right)$.

I've found that $D_{\alpha}=\left\{\left(x,y\right) \in \mathbb{R}^2, \ y+xy \leq \alpha \right\}$ but now I'm asked to find the conditional law
$$
Z|\left(X=x\right) $$
and i dont know how to proceed, how could I do that ?